# Get react element string type

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have a component that renders the following:

```
<div>
  <Example/>
  <span>hi</span>
</div>
```

The property `this.props.children` will be an array with two elements. When looped over `child.type` works only for span to return the string `span`, what property is there that will give me the string `Example` for a react element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the component class has a display name, you should be able to use `child.type.displayName`. [This example](https://jsbin.com/bixijal/edit?js,console,output) demonstrates.

Comment: JSX automatically populates this field using the variable name, so it should be set in most cases, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this to get the string regardless if it's a native DOM Element or ReactElement.

```
function getStringType (node) {
  if (typeof node.type === 'string') return node.type
  if (node.type && node.type.displayName) return node.type.displayName
  return false
}
```

Comment: Maybe lines 3 and 4 can be replaced by 

"return node.type && node.type.displayName"

That will also take care of the explicit false statement you are returning to have consistent returns. can't suggest edit, as edit queue is full